# How can I use Garnish to sort?

Tags: sorting, garnish

I am working on a field type that is similar to the table field type. Is it possible to tap into Garnish for the sorting. I’ve tried a few things and have had no luck. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, I've had experience with two different types of sorting with [SuperTable](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable/blob/master/supertable/resources/js/SuperTableInput.js#L32) (check the link for associated JS).

If you're modelling the fieldtype after a table, you might like to use the `Craft.DataTableSorter` method. Its pretty restrictive to a table layout, and you'll need to give each `tr` element a `data-id`.

```
Craft.FieldType = Garnish.Base.extend({
    sorter: null,

    init: function() {
        var $table = $container.children('.table');

        this.sorter = new Craft.DataTableSorter($table, {
            helperClass: 'editabletablesorthelper',
            copyDraggeeInputValuesToHelper: true
        });
    },

    addRow: function() {
        var $tr = $('<tr/>');
        this.sorter.addItems($tr);
    }
});
```

Or, for more abstract sorting, you can have more control using `Garnish.DragSort` - essentially a general drag and sort function. This is what Matrix uses.

```
Craft.FieldType = Garnish.Base.extend({
    sorter: null,

    init: function() {
        var $rows = $container.children('.table-rows');

        this.sorter = new Garnish.DragSort($rows, {
            handle: 'tfoot .move',
            axis: 'y',
            collapseDraggees: true,
            magnetStrength: 4,
            helperLagBase: 1.5,
            helperOpacity: 0.9,
        });
    },

    addRow: function() {
        var $tr = $('<tr/>');
        this.sorter.addItems($tr);
    }
});
```